# standalone asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, capability

i want to test my web hosts asp.net capabilities - equivalent to a 'phpinfo' page - is there a standalone aspx page I can upload to test that asp.net is correctly running and what version etc it is running.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Cody said, a blank default.aspx page should work, but I recommend enabling tracing for the page as well to get some more useful information about your host's ASP.NET setup ie

```
<%@ Page Trace="true" %>
```

[MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Can you just make a blank default.aspx page with nothing but <% Response.Write("Hello World") %> in the source.?